# Cocoapods - Create pod for a private iOS repository

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I have a repo with code which I do not want to share with others. But I want to have a pod which others can integrate in their applications. Is that possible ? I followed [this](https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/create-and-distribute-private-libraries-with-cocoapods-5b6507b57a03) tutorial but got the error on trying to add this on a different system :
**Unable to find specification for 'pod_name'.**
Here is the pod file :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/my_source_url'

target 'DemoPods' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

 # Pods for DemoPods

pod 'MyPodName'

end
```

**My use case :**

- Keep my repository private so that source code can't be accessed.
- Create Pod for my private repo.
- Other users should be able to add the pod in their projects.

Answer (score 7):

To distribute a closed source pod you first need to modify your private repository so that you can produce a `.xcframework` file.

### Distribute through a URL

You have to zip the `.xcframework` file and make it available through a URL to your audience. (whether this is public or private)

Then you can create a `.podspec` file like this:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name = '<POD_NAME>'
    s.version = '<VERSION>'
    s.summary = '<SUMMARY>'
    s.description = <<-DESC
    <DESCRIPTION>
                         DESC
  
    s.homepage = '<A_URL_TO_A_WEBPAGE>'
    s.author = { '<AUTHOR_NAME>' => '<AUTHOR_EMAIL>' }
    s.source = { :http => '<URL_TO_YOUR_ZIP_FILE>' }

    ...

    s.vendored_frameworks = '<PATH_OF_XCFRAMEWORK_FILE_IN_THE_ZIP>.xcframework'
end
```

After that there are 2 methods to distribute it:

- **Public**: If you want to distribute your pod through cocoapods specs    repo, you can push your `.podspec` file to the cocoapods
  trunk following [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html#release) guide:

  ```
  pod trunk push <PATH_TO_YOUR_PODSPEC_FILE>.podspec
  ```

  The installation from the users will be like any other pod:

  ```rb
  use_frameworks!

  target 'TargetName' do
    pod '<POD_NAME>'
  end
  ```

  **Private**: For private distribution follow [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html#-add-your-pods-podspec-to-your-repo) guide, create a
  private specs repo and use the following command to push your podspec:

  ```
  pod repo push <REPO_NAME> <PATH_TO_YOUR_PODSPEC_FILE>.podspec
  ```

  The installation from the users will be like this:

  ```rb
  use_frameworks!

  target 'TargetName' do
    pod '<POD_NAME>', :source => '<PRIVATE_SPECS_REPO_URL>'
  end
  ```
- **Public**: If you don't mind about cocoapods specs repo (**or if you
  want to test your `.podspec` file**) you can make your `.podspec` file
  publicly available through a URL and then instruct the users to use
  the **podspec** way in their `Podfile` to install your pod:

  ```rb
  use_frameworks!

  target 'TargetName' do
    pod '<POD_NAME>', podspec: '<URL_TO_YOUR_PODSPEC_FILE>.podspec'
  end
  ```

  **Private**: The same method also applies to the private distribution,
  as long as your users are the only ones that known or have access to
  the podspec URL.

### Distribute through a Github repo

Although I don't recommend committing a binary file (which is the `.xcframework`) into a git repo, you can pretty much do the same using a git repo but without the need to zip your `.xcframework` file.

Create a git repository and add the `.xcframework` file along with a `.podspec` file like this:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name = '<POD_NAME>'
    s.version = '<VERSION>'
    s.summary = '<SUMMARY>'
    s.description = <<-DESC
    <DESCRIPTION>
                         DESC
  
    s.homepage = '<A_URL_TO_A_WEBPAGE>'
    s.author = { '<AUTHOR_NAME>' => '<AUTHOR_EMAIL>' }
    s.source = { :git => '<URL_TO_YOUR_GIT_REPO>.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

    ...

    s.vendored_frameworks = '<PATH_OF_XCFRAMEWORK_FILE_IN_THE_REPO>.xcframework'
end
```

**Public**: Then you can distribute your pod through cocoapods specs repo by pushing your `.podspec` file to the cocoapods trunk like this:

```
pod trunk push <PATH_TO_YOUR_PODSPEC_FILE>.podspec
```

**Private**: For private distribution, you can create a private specs repo and use the following command to push your podspec:

```
pod repo push <REPO_NAME> <PATH_TO_YOUR_PODSPEC_FILE>.podspec
```

Comment: Aren't both the above methods ways to publicly distribute the framework ? I want the distribution to be private using pods.

Comment: @Nitish sorry, the distribution audience wasn't so clear and I assumed that will be public. So, you want to distribute your pod **as a framework** and using a **private specs repo**?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Framework as a pod but with private repo.

Comment: @Nitish in that case you can definitely use the second method but without pushing to the cocoapods trunk. I am checking if the first also works.

Comment: In this link it's mentioned [here](https://success.mirantis.com/article/can-other-users-search-and-view-my-private-repositories) that we need to add the users on git to whom we want to provide the access (if we have a pod). I am not sure if this would be feasible solution considering I don't want to add the user on git overtime a new user wants to use my library.

Comment: @Nitish yes, but that's the point of private distribution of a pod, to have complete control of the users that have access to your pod. Sorry if I missed something.

Comment: @gcharita if source url is private and podspec is public , is there anyway to prompt for password via Cocoapods?

Comment: @ParagBafna I just tested that using the **podspec** way of my answer. You can add this line `pod '<POD_NAME>', podspec: '<URL_TO_YOUR_PODSPEC_FILE>.podspec'` in your `Podfile`. (with `URL_TO_YOUR_PODSPEC_FILE` be a public URL) Then, when you run `pod install` in terminal, you will be asked to insert the private repository credentials. (unless they already exist in the keychain)

Comment: @gcharita Thanks. My source is http and on pod install its failing with "curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403". My podspec is public but framework is private

Comment: I am not using git repo for hosting .zip file

Comment: @ParagBafna oh now I see. You are probably using http authentication for your .zip file. The issue with `curl` and the option `-n` has been fixed. (just tested with the latest cocoapods version) Check [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5055) issue. So, you can use an `.netrc` file in your home direcroty with your credentials.

Comment: i did exactly like you said by putting the xcframework on a zip public link
spec.source = { :http => 'https://github.com/***/***-sdk-mobile-ios-app-**-example/raw/main/****.xcframework.zip' }



 spec.vendored_frameworks = '***.xcframework'
but i'm getting error it's like it didn't fond sources :
ld: library 'Bey***eClient' not found

Comment: ld: library '***Client' not found it's like it didn't find sources

Comment: @tamtoum1987 unfortunately I cannot tell for sure what exactly is the problem. Check if you need to change the path of `vendored_frameworks` parameter in `.podspec` file.

Comment: it's the correct path can we talk on slack or other plateform please ?

Comment: i'm on this problem since 2 days :(

Comment: @tamtoum1987 https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256876/cocoapods-create-pod-for-a-private-ios-repository

Comment: when i use vendored_libraries instead of vendored_frameworks it's seems to work :( it's srange

Comment: i send you some message on chat

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intentions correctly, you want to make your library public without opening the source code. In this case, you should check out the example of GoogleWebRTC. This is their [pods config](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/c/6/GoogleWebRTC/1.1.31999/GoogleWebRTC.podspec.json).

In this case, your cocoapod library would simply be a container for the built framework. For example, you can create a public repository, which will store the information needed for cocoapods and the built framework itself. I think It's even possible to configure github to publish builds from your private repo to the public one, but it may be a little bit challenging.

You can check out [this guide](https://medium.com/onfido-tech/distributing-compiled-swift-frameworks-via-cocoapods-8cb67a584d57)

Comment: But the code is public. I can see the source code.

Comment: If you're talking about a pods config link I've included, it's a pod config file in the cocoapods repository - it contains configs for all public pods. As usually you only mention a name in your podfile, there need to be a source of truth. This particular config only contains a link to a built GoogleWebRTC.framework (https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/eae5bee0861b6f47/GoogleWebRTC-1.1.31999.tar.gz"), and doesn't have the source code. I've added a link to a guide on how make such pod.

Answer (score 0):

Here what worked for me

Create xcarchive for simulator

```
  xcodebuild archive \
  -scheme BClient \
  -archivePath "archives/BClient-iOS-simulator.xcarchive" \
  -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

Create xcarchive for device

```
  xcodebuild archive \
  -scheme BClient \
  -archivePath "archives/BClient-iOS.xcarchive" \
  -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

I Combine them to get xcframework framework

```
   xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
  -framework "archives/BClient-      iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/BClient.framework" \
  -framework "archives/BClient-iOS-      simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/BClient.framework" \
  -output "BClient.xcframework"
```

After that i zip the BClient.xcframework to get BClient.zip i publish it to public repo to get url like that : https://github.com/******example/raw/main/BClient.zip

For the BClient.podspec :

```
   Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

   spec.name = "BClient"

   spec.version = "0.0.6"

   spec.summary = "B Client iOS"

   spec.description = "B Client for iOS"

   spec.homepage = "example.com"

   spec.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }

   spec.author = { "B O" => "o.b@gmail.com" }

   spec.platform = :ios, "15.2"

   spec.swift_version = '5.9'

   spec.source = { :http => 'https://github.com/******example/raw/main/BClient.zip' }
    spec.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'BClient.xcframework'

   end
```

After this configuration the command passed successfuly :

```
  pod trunk push BClient.podspec --verbose --allow-warnings --use-libraries
```